# mysql 5.5 invalid escape sequence java

Tags: java, mysql, escaping

```
static byte[] ac = {'\\', '\'', '{', '}', '{'}; //not OK insert into tt values('\\\'{}{')
static byte[] ac = {'\\', '\'', '{', '}'}; //OK insert into tt values('\\\'{}')
static byte[] ac = {'\\', '\'', '{'}; //OK insert into tt values('\\\'{')
static byte[] ac = {'\'', '{', '}', '{'}; //OK insert into tt values('\'{}{')
static byte[] ac = {'\\', '{', '}', '{'}; //OK insert into tt values('\\{}{')
```

- Ubuntu system
- MySQL 5.5
- MySQL JDBC 5.1.22

I am not able to insert 5 bytes to a blob table field, the bytes are shown above. 
The datasource connection encoding is set to `UTF-8`.

Relevant information: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-literals.html

Any idea why `{}` is so special? it works with workbench.

For the not ok, i got the following exception:

`java.sql.SQLException: Not a valid escape sequence: {')`

Comment: How do you insert this values? Show the code!

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in some versions of MySQL's JDBC client (Connector/J); see http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=31457 (and other bugs linked from there). You should be able to fix it by upgrading to the latest Connector/J; alternatively, you can work around it by disabling escape-processing (by writing `Statement.setEscapeProcessing(false)`).

Comment: Does this problem also happen with prepared statements? Because if it doesn't, then using a PreparedStatement is the much cleaner and safer solution.

Comment: so someone has already encounter this, sorry, I was not able to google it out. appreciated! thank you for the information.